# Pitfalls in modifying an object in two processes?

Tags: python, oop, parallel-processing

I am trying to speed up a class that is currently pulling data from a database.

```
class Foo:
   def __init__(self):
       self.build()

   def build(self):

       # The order of execution does not matter
       self.get_data1()
       self.get_data2()
       self.get_data3()

   def get_data1(self):
       self.data1 = slow_get_data1_from_database()

   def get_data2(self):
       self.data2 = slow_get_data2_from_database()

   def get_data3(self):
       self.data3 = slow_get_data3_from_database()
```

I think I should be able to call `get_data1`, `get_data2` and `get_data3` in parallel, and it seems to work based on my testing.

However, this also makes my code sense tingle, and it may be a problem waiting to happen. **Is there anything I should know about modifying different attributes of a Python object in parallel threads?**

The code for `build_in_parallel` is

```
from joblib import Parallel, delayed, parallel_backend

def exec_in_parallel(callables:list[(Callable, 'args', 'kwargs')], n_jobs=1):
    '''Use joblib to execute the callables via c(*args, **kwargs) for c in callables'''
    
    with parallel_backend('threading', n_jobs=n_jobs):
        ans = Parallel(verbose=False)(delayed(c)(*args, **kwargs) for c, args, kwargs in callables)
    
    return ans

class Bar(Foo):
    def build_in_parallel(self):
        exec_in_parallel([
            (self.get_data1, [], {}),
            (self.get_data2, [], {}),
            (self.get_data3, [], {}),
        ], n_jobs=-1)
```

Comment: What do the functions really do? If they run Python code, you wouldn't see much of a speedup due to GIL lock contention. If they all shoot off, say, an SQL query and spend most of their time waiting for it, then it's a different story.

Comment: Beyond that, Python variables are perfectly thread-safe and you don't need to worry – though I'd personally think it'd be cleaner to load data first, then build a `Foo` based on it, rather than have a `Foo` populate itself.

Comment: Good to know. The get_data functions spend 99% of their runtime waiting for the db to return data. I am using this Foo class as a sort of facade pattern -  there is about 15 different get_data functions, and it'd be a pain to remember to call each one every time.

Comment: Well, then maybe a `@classmethod def fetch(self, ...):` on `Foo`?